# Do disjointed nouns (eg in lists) need articles?

Tags: articles, lists

The list items are really just titles. Do they need articles?

1. **The** meeting

   - Discussing problems
   - **An** unforgettable present
2. **The** audience

   - Targeting right audiences

Comment: It's more about articles. Do you mean that it's better to go with no articles in this case?

Comment: It's not about articles, infinitives, or gerunds. It's about whether or not it's meaningful to ask syntax-related questions in the context of names for items in lists.

Comment: I just want to know whether it's necessary to use articles in the example I've posted.

Comment: Your examples are just noun phrases, with no syntactic context within which to consider whether an article (definite OR indefinite) might be expected or not.

Comment: Alright, let me be more specific. In these 'noun phrases' examples, are those articles necessary or can they be reasonably omitted? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Without a full context, it's completely meaningless to ask whether any given noun phrase should or shouldn't include an article (and if so, which *specific* article). And sometimes *even then* there's no meaningfully "correct" answer - for example, the second word in the first sentence of this comment is an indefinite article, but it could equally well have been the *definite* article OR the "zero" article.

Comment: I got it, thank you. But the problem is that the above example is what I have to figure out. Imagine that this is the list with these items. If you wrote that, would you add any articles (highlighted in bold). I'd be extremely grateful for that.

Comment: I probably wouldn't include articles unless I knew enough about the *specific* context to affect my choice, but really you should be trying to realign your thinking so you can understand *why it's a meaningless question*. Unless you've got actual ***utterances*** (with any relevant ***context***) featuring your np's, you won't ***learn*** anything from "answers" here.